# WAVE extension not detecting label + aria-labelledby

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

I have an input field with a two part label, specified by `aria-labelledby`:

```
<p id="label2">Part 2</p>
<label id="label1">Part 1</label>
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="label1 label2">
```

When I run the WAVE extension (version 1.0.9) in Chrome, the `<label>` is flagged as orphaned, but the `input` itself is seen as properly labeled/described.

Am I wrong to be using a `<label>` there since there won't be a `for` attribute, or is the tool just having trouble connecting the IDs in the `aria-labelledby` to the `label`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there is no conformance issue with your code, the control has a visible label and its [accessible name](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/04/what-is-an-accessible-name/) is a concatenation of the 2 visible labels, there is an accessibility/usability improvement that could be made by making proper use of the `label` element. If you associate `label` element with the `input` using `for/id` the `label` becomes clickable and focus is moved to the `input` when the `label` is clicked, thus increasing the clickable area to focus the control. A side effect being that WAVE should no longer complain.

```
<p id="label2a">Part 2</p> 
<label id="label1a" for="t1">Part 1</label>   
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="label1a label2a" id="t1">
```

[test case](https://s.codepen.io/stevef/debug/eVvLed)

Answer (score 3):

The `label` element that is not associated to a control. While your input does use ARIA to reference the label element, the semantics of the `label` are not being utilized - it could just as well be a `span`. An orphaned label *typically* indicates an accessibility issue, thus the WAVE alert.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the WAVE extension doesn't validate aria-labeledby. So if you have 2 label elements which are associated with an input using the for attribute and use aria-labeledby as prescribed by the "How to Fix it" section in the extension, it will still complain.

[example](https://cdpn.io/pen/debug/VwxJZgN)